# Difference between WinCE7 vs. WEC7

Tags: windows-embedded-compact

I tried searching for training for Windows Embedded Compact 7 and I found that some of the training mention Windows CE 7. So, I would like to know if there is there a difference between Windows CE 7 and Windows Embedded Compact 7. Or do these 2 refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

These are the same thing.

The modular Windows OS for embedded systems was called "Windows Compact Embedded" or "Windows CE" up until version 6. For version 7, Microsoft changed the name to "Windows Embedded Compact" for some reason.

People still call it "CE7" out of habit though.